# Jquery onclick change value

Tags: jquery, view, toggle

I have some jquery tabs on my page the code for them is:

```
//tabs options
$("#tabs").tabs({ collapsible: true,  selected: -1 });
```

I want to create a button that will toggle the above option 'selected: -1'

I need it to change the value of 'selected' to '0' then back to '-1'

How would I do this?

```
<a href="#">Toggle View</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<a href="#" id="toggle">Toggle View</a>
```

Then use the [`.toggle()` function](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), like this:

```
$("#toggle").toggle(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", -1);
}, function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", 0);  
});
```

When you use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), it'll cycle through the functions you pass in on each click, so on the first click the first function runs, next click the next, etc...if you pass only 2 functions, you're toggling between them on each click.

Answer (score 0):

Nick is right.

You can use the `.toggle()` to switch between the values.

Since you need a button to toggle the value you may add this too along with Nick's code.

`<button>Switch</button>`

`$("button").click(function () {
$("#toggle").toggle(...)});`